# Laravel Passport create dynamic refresh token expiration time

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I have Oauth2 authentication in Laravel with Passport.
I want my first party clients have different refresh token expiration time.
I used client credential so, how can I achieve this with best practices.

Comment: "how can I achieve this with best practices" Try the way documentation suggests and post back error if you face any.

Comment: Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(15));    that is from the docs.  You would put that in your boot method in your AuthServiceProvider.php file.